# Active Directory - Getting newly created account details

Tags: active-directory

I need to fetch account details which are newly created in active directory less than 30 mins. I have to do this periodically.

I am thinking to use search filters for getting these details. But i have no idea how to use search filters while searching in AD.

Can any one tell me how can i get details of new accounts.

Thanks,
Narendra

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a link for the search filter syntax:  [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa746475(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa746475%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Also, in addition to the DirectoryEntry objects and DirectorySearcher objects in [System.DirectoryServices](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.aspx), there is the [System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.aspx) assembly / namespace that contains classes more specialized to working with security information.

I obviously come from the .NET world, but if you just want something simple to query AD, try [ADFind](http://www.joeware.net/freetools/tools/adfind/index.htm).  It is a command line tool for querying AD.

Answer (score 0):

If you're familiar with .NET you could write a simple C# or VB application and leverage the [Directory Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.aspx) namespace that is provided as a .NET library.

Joe Kaplan and Ryan Dunn wrote a good book covering Directory Services called [The .NET Developer's Guide to Directory Services Programming](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321350170) and they have a compainion website with samples from the book that you can leverage called [Directory Programming .NET](http://directoryprogramming.net/)